# How can i run lightbox jquery in one html page more time

Tags: jquery, html

How to run lightbox jquery in html page multiple time. ?
Can i run one jquery multiple time in single html page ?

the code which i used is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#gallery a').lightBox();
});
</script>

<div id="gallery">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="photos/ilPunto-cat1.jpg" target="_parent">
             <img src="photos/ilPunto_cat1.jpg" class="left"/>
        </a>
</li>
```

Comment: once included go with classes  :)

Comment: By calling it multiple times?  Show the code that's _not_ working and explain what the problem is and where it occurs.

Comment: as far as i get your question,,you need to use classes..All this is mentioned on the plugin website..read those instructions man and then if any problem refine your question..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply Lightbox to more images than those inside your gallery then

```
$(function() {
    $('#gallery1 a').lightBox();
    $('#gallery2 ul li a').lightBox();
});
```

or

```
$(function() {
    $('#gallery1 a, #gallery2 ul li a').lightBox();
});
```

I recommend the first piece of code. Lot more flexible.